# Weird bug while adding a NSDictionary to an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I got a really weird bug in my app today:

```
NSMutableDictionary *testLocal = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[testLocal setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"title"];
[testLocal setObject:@"test notification" forKey:@"body"];
[testLocal setObject:@"1" forKey:@"repeat"];
[testLocal setObject:@"26.04.2011 - 12:53" forKey:@"start"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[saver read]];
[[dict objectForKey:@"content"] addObject:testLocal]; //Crashes here! (SIGABRT)
```

The method `[saver read]` returns this:

```
{
    content =     (
                {
            body = "test notification";
            repeat = 1;
            start = "26.04.2011 - 13.06";
            title = Test;
        }
    );
}
```

So I don't see the error because the dict I write to is mutable and the key "content" is an array.

Thanks in advance.
mavrick3.

[saver read]:

```
- (NSDictionary *)read {
    return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];
}
```

Comment: Can you post code in `[saver read]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking out what class the object returned by `[dict objectForKey:@"content"]` is. Then things will be much clearer to you. I suspect it is not returning an `NSMutableArray` instance but something else, most likely `NSArray` which doesn't respond to method `addObject:`

Comment: This is indeed the most likely explanation, though do note that arrays are really implemented by CoreFoundation, so sending `-class` to them is typically not a helpful thing to do.  Looking at the crash report should tell the OP what the problem is in any case.

Answer (score 1):

From apple Documentation for [objectForKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDictionary) :

The value associated with aKey, or **nil** if no value is associated with aKey.

So your code could be like below

```
if([dict objectForKey:@"content"] != nil && [[dict objectForKey:@"content"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] )
{
  [[dict objectForKey:@"content"] addObject:testLocal];
} 
else
{
   [dict setObject: textLocal forKey: @"content"];
}
```

Comment: I must say that you are wrong. It is perfectly fine to write [nil addObject:anObject]; and that won't cause a crash. However, [[NSArray array] addObject:anObject]; will cause SIGABRT.

Comment: This answer is very definitely wrong, and the pattern it suggests (unnecessarily testing for `nil`) is wrong too.

Comment: Sorry it is still wrong :) [dict objectForKey:@"content"]; could return an NSArray, NSString etc... The if clause would pass as true and then you would get the SIGABRT again unless it returned an NSMutableArray. You could do a [[dict objectForKey:@"content"] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] check, but not before reading this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:

Answer (score 0):

Is the array to which you want to add a dictionary mutable?